# Create a WebHook for AzureDevOps in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, webhooks

I'm trying to create a custom WebHook for our Team. This WebHook should be called when a build is successfully completed.

The steps I'm using are the following:

**First** I create a REST Api which will be my WebHook, this looks like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WebHookController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<WebHookController> _logger;

    public WebHookController(ILogger<WebHookController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // POST: /webhook
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post() // Which object should my endpoint expect from AzureDevOps?
    {
        try
        {
             // Some logic here based on projectId   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"WebHookController: Post:  {ex}");
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

**Second** I would host this API somewhere and then in AzureDevOps register this WebHook, like the below:

[image]

**My question:**

In the `Post` method what object is sent by AzureDevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We provide one button **Test** which you can run it to get what are the JSON sent by Azure devops:

[image]

After run with Test, our system will run a virtual pipeline to send a request.

---

If trying with `Test` button, **there's no need to input a valid URL values into URL blank**. Just keep it not empty since it is a required argument.

After click on Test,  change the tab to Request and you will see what you want:

[image]

Comment: That was so easy. The answer was just in front of my eyes. Thank you very much.